# generate a list with adjecant pair of co-primes

Tags: c, algorithm, primes

Given N elements such that each element from 1 to N-1 appears exactly once except one. Your task is very very simple . Arrange these elements in any order such that each pair of adjacent elements is coprime .Suppose we have 5 elements A1 , A2 , A3 , A4 , A5 and the desired order is any arbitrary order B1 , B2 , B3 , B4 , B5 such that.

```
gcd(B1,B2) = gcd(B2,B3) = gcd(B3,B4) = gcd(B4,B5) =1.
```

**INPUT:**

First line of input contains a single integer N denoting the number of elements. Next line of the input contains N space separated integers denoting the N elements.

**OUTPUT:**

Output consists of N space separated integers denoting a valid sequence according to the mentioned conditions .

CONSTRAINTS:

```
N<=5*10^6

A[i] <= [common sense]
```

All the values are strictly according to the constraints.

I TRIED This out. PLEASE SUGGEST A BETTER ALGORITHM.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int coprime(int num1 , int num2)
 {
     while(num2%num1!=0)
     {
          int rem= num2%num1;
          num2=num1;
          num1=rem;
     }
     return (num1==1);
}

int main()
{
    long int *arr , n , i=0 ,j ,k , p,flag=0,t;
    puts("enter the no of elements");
    scanf("%ld" ,&n);
    arr=(long int*)malloc(n*sizeof(long int));
    p=n;

    while(i<n)
    {
        scanf("%ld",&arr[i]);

        if(arr[i]==0)
            break;
        i++;
    }

    for(i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
    {
        if(!flag)
            p--;
        k=arr[p];

        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            if(coprime(k,arr[j]))
            {

                if(coprime(k,arr[j+1]))
                {
                    for(t=n; t>j+1 ; t--)
                    {
                        arr[t]=arr[t-1];
                    }
                    arr[j+1]=k;
                    j++;
                }
                else if(j>0&&coprime(k,arr[j-1]))
                {
                    for(t=n; t>j ; t--)
                    {
                        arr[t]=arr[t-1];
                    }
                    arr[j]=k;

                }
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("%ld " ,arr[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **unrelated to the answer**: Your last `else` in the `coprime` function is suprefluous.

Comment: Doesn't even run, just sits there forever. Sounds like a homework question anyway.

Comment: You should use functions, it's not really easy to understand the intent of your program.

Comment: what if the input is (the numbers): 2, 4, 8, 10, 13, 11, 16, 18

Comment: giorgim, the elements must be consecutive. Each of them appears once except for one which appears twice. The input is organized in an extremely inefficient way: Instead of just giving N and the number that appears twice, all the numbers are given, and one of them twice. That's at least what the description explains.

Comment: @HansKlünder: If I understood correctly I just asked OP for scenario: that there maybe some numbers which you can't order as pairwise coprime, do you see what I mean? See my sequence of numbers. How can you order them such that neighbors are coprime?

Comment: giorgim, you are right, they can't be ordered, not in a way that neighbors are always co-primes. I interpret the text `each element from 1 to N-1 appears exactly once except one` such that your proposed input is not allowed. In your case, N=8, thus the numbers should be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,n where n is any number from 1 to 7. It have to confess that that seems to be a strange problem definition, and I am not sure that the OP actually meant what he wrote.

Comment: @giorgim . test cases int he input assume that the input provided will be such that it can be arranged as a sequence of coprimes

Comment: @iharob the last else in the coprime function works for the nos that are not co prime for exmaple  u can say 4,6 .

Comment: @AmitChawla it's not needed, if the condition is `false` you will return from the function anyway. You can actually just `return (num1 == 1)`.

Comment: @AmitChawla now it's worse, you should just `return (num1 == 1)` without any `if`.

Comment: @iharob got your point. can u suggest a better algorithm for this? as asked in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple solution: let's assume that the number that is present twice is `x`. Then the answer is `{x, 1, 2, 3, ..., n - 1}`. Why does it work? `gcd(x, 1) = 1` for any `x` and `gcd(a, a + 1) = 1` for any `a`. Thus, this ordering is correct.